# Count Characters after a certain pattern

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contains a column "Code" where the records have the following format "xx-xxx" and "xx-xx", for the later format i want to add a zero after the "-" to make it "xx-0xx", is there anyway to count the characters after a certain pattern in Mysql

Comment: You will find everything you need here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.  If those are your only two possibilities, you can use `case`:

```
select (case when length(code) = 5
             then replace(code, '-', '-0')
             else code
        end) as new_code
```

If you want to be more general, deconstruct the string and build it back again:

```
select concat_ws('-', substring_index(code, '-', 1),
                 lpad(substring_index(code, '-', -1), 3, '0')
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the CHAR_LENGTH(str) like this:

```
SELECT code,CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTR(code,3))
from table
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this function returns the length of the string in parameter, what i want exactly is counting the number of characters after a certain pattern like the dash in my case.